# How to enable Auto Complete in PHPStorm for CakePHP templates

Tags: cakephp, phpstorm, cakephp-3.0

How to enable Auto Complete in **PHPStorm** for **CakePHP** templates.

For example `$this` and its functions, `Helpers` ... etc in the `*.ctp` files

Comment: There is now also a [IdeHelper](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper) plugin to support IDEs like PHPStorm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a type hint comment on top of your view code:

```
<?php
/* @var $this \App\View\AppView */
```

---

For the records, in pre-namespaced CakePHP/2.x it used to be:

```
<?php
/* @var $this View */
```

Comment: With a default app skeleton, it should be `\App\View\AppView`.

Comment: @ndm Thanks for the tip (I hadn't noticed the 3.0 tag; mine is code for 2.0).

Comment: It should be `/** @var \App\View\AppView $this */`, I agree.